# Table pictures alignment issue

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

For the first time I am posting here cause if usually I am able to find a solution to my code issues throughout other answers, this time, no matter what I try, it doesn't work.

I am doing a table with two rows with basically pictures on the first row linking some PDF docs with a title below (second row).

The thing is that pictures do not have the same size (that can't be change). I would like them to be align on the bottom of the row, with a small margin before the separation line.

Right now, they are centered (by default I guess) which is not bad but not what I want anyway.
The second issue that I have while they are centered is that the first picture of of the row is always a bit higher than the rest for some reason. Can't figure out why.

Hopefully you can help me with the code written below (I assume that its full of mistakes since several calls doesn't work and could probably be removed).

```
<table width="780"; bgcolor="#e8e8e8" style="table-layout:fixed" VALIGN="top">

<tr>


<td style="word-wrap: break-word;"; ALIGN="CENTER">
<div align="center";>

<a href="PDF URL" target="_blank">
        <img src="URL" alt="ALT">
    </a>
</div>
</td>

<td>
<div align="center">
<a href="PDF URL" target="_blank">
       <img src="URL" alt="ALT">
    </a>
</div>
</td>

<td>
<div align="center">
<a href="PDF URL" target="_blank">
       <img src="URL" alt="ALT">
    </a>
</div>
</td>



</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="center"><p style="font-size:11px"><a title="TITLE1" href="URL" target="_blank">TITLE1</p></a>
</div></td>
<td><div align="center"><p style="font-size:11px"><a title="TITLE2" href="URL" target="_blank">TITLE2</p></a>
</div></td>
<td><div align="center"><p style="font-size:11px"><a title="TITLE3" href="URL" target="_blank">TITLE3</p></a>
</div></td>
<td><div align="center"><p style="font-size:11px"><a title="TITLE4" href="URL" target="_blank">TITLE4</p></a>
</div></td>

{/tr}
{/table}
```

Comment: What kind of HTML is this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am a complete beginner in this matter and as far as I know, I am doing wrong by mixing html and css things (if that sentence makes sense...)

Comment: HTML uses `<>` brackets and CSS uses `{}`, you need to study alot

Comment: OW, I changed all the "<" to "{" cause I was not allowed to post properly for some reasons.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should first include a .css file call in your header like this:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Then u can create a "mystyle.css" file in order to apply all the styles you want for your table.

Take a look at this page. [W3School - CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

There u have some examples about how to change color, margin, background images and so on.

EDIT:

If you want o apply all the styles in the .html file try looking at this web. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/

There u have all html tags, select the one u want and see the attributes  could use.

Comment: I have fixed the bracket issue.
Flowen, the problem is that I am not admin and can't add or change a style template.

I am stuck with inpage options.

I will try the inpage CSS style header though.

Comment: Thanks Flowen, it is already way better and it is very simple to use. I have added the following line to the CSS style header and it makes great changes already: 
     td { vertical-align: bottom }

Comment: The last issue I am facing now is that the first picture of the table is always a bit higher than the rest of the pictures of the row for some reason.
Can't figure out why ..

Comment: Look if all the images have the same heigt and width, that could be the problem maybe. You can give all the images the same width="100px" and height="100px" in order to be identical. Tick as best answer if it helps ^^

Comment: If the first advice worked, however this one doesn't. I still have the first picture a bit shifted on the top (like 15-20px above the bot line where all the other are aligned). I have ticked your answer as best anyway!

Comment: I dont know why is displaying like this. You can give some margin just to the first image to lower a bit. margin-top:"10px";

Comment: It doesn't work. I am probably not doing the right thing since I can't see a single difference (I have put the px to 100 for this purpose). The line should be <td margin-top:"100px"> ?

Comment: I have been able to get the code line working and it moves the whole row, not the specified cell only.
I should actually do something on the picture itself I guess

Comment: margin-top is a css property. Specify a class to the img.  <img src="URL" alt="ALT" class"move-img">. Then, go to your .css file and add: .move-img{margin-top:"10px";}